# django-channels websocketbridge error

Tags: django-channels

I am pretty new to django-channels.
while trying to set websocketbridge I ran into an errorin my JS:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: channels is not defined

I loaded websocketbridge.js on top of my html template:

```
% load staticfiles %}
{% static "channels/js/websocketbridge.js" %}
```

and in my JS I have tried both:

```
const webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge(); // try 1
const webSocketBridge = new WebSocketBridge(); // try 2
```

which are raising a similar error. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this one pretty quick but I am leaving a solution for beginners like me who might find themselves into the same problem.

In my case, I am just handling the static files a bit differently so I just changed

```
{% static "channels/js/websocketbridge.js" %}
```

on top of my html template to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/channels/js/websocketbridge.js' %}"></script>
```

at the bottom of the template body, where I load specific static files and other js scripts.

Hope that helps.